# Why is `f(?=\=)` invailid regex in VSCode?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace, regex-lookarounds

In VSCode if I use `f(?=\=)` in the regex find and replace I get an error that says:

```
Invalid regular expression: /f(?=\=)/: Invalid escape
```

however, if I do `f(?==)` it works fine. I don't see any issue with the first regex, its just a specifying the literal `=` sign as a positive lookahead. Why can you not escape an `=` sign?

Comment: `\=` is an “unnecessary identity escape” in this context. Most likely VSCode treats these as errors (they’re not always errors in other contexts).

Comment: Is there a reason you are adding the escape, ie, is there a reason why `f(?==)` doesn't meet your needs? Or are you just trying to understand how it works?

Comment: @xdhmoore, I mistakenly thought that `=` was a special character, so I escaped it.

Comment: @Kalcifer I guess it refuses to be special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex, `(?=` starts a positive lookahead, but your second `=` is the part being matched, not part of that specific syntax. So the slash is interpreted as an escape, and an escaped `=` sign is invalid.